# Spring-boot, JUnit tests using different profiles

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, junit, integration-testing

I'm trying to use application.properties profiles for integration tests using JUnit in order to check two different platforms.

I tried doing so with basic configuration file `application.properties` which contains the common configurations for both platforms, and on top of that I've added properties files `application-tensorflow.properties` `application-caffe.properties` for each platform, which have specific platform configurations, but I found out that it works differently in JUnit than the approach I used to use in the main application.

my test configuration class looks like this:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
@CompileStatic
@EnableConfigurationProperties
class TestConfig {...}
```

I'm using `@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")` so it will recognize my basic configurations, there I also write `spring.profiles.active=tensorflow`, in hope that it will recognize the tensorflow application profile however it doesn't read from the file: `/src/test/resources/application-tensorflow.properties`, nor from `/src/main/resources/application-tensorflow.properties` as it does in main app.

Is there special a way to specify a spring profile in JUnit test? What is the best practice to achieve what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

First: Add `@ActiveProfiles` to your test class to define the active profiles.

Also, you need to configure that config files should be loaded. There are two options:

- In a simple integration test with `@ContextConfiguration(classes = TheConfiguration.class, initializers = ConfigFileApplicationContextInitializer.class)`
- In a full Spring Boot test with `@SpringBootTest`

Example test class:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@ActiveProfiles({ "test" })
public class DummyTest {

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @Test
    public void readProps() {
        String value = env.getProperty("prop1") + " " + env.getProperty("prop2");
        assertEquals("Hello World", value);
    }
}
```

Now the files `src/test/resources/application.properties` and `src/test/resources/application-test.properties` are evaluated.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried annotating your test with

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@ActiveProfiles(profiles = {"tensorflow"})
```

Also make sure application-tensorflow.properties is under /src/test/resources

Comment: yes, and I don't understand why it doesn't access the tensorflow.application file after I specify the profile in many variations.

Comment: Have you annotated your test with @SpringBootTest and @RunWith(SpringRunner.class) ? Is application-tensorflow.properties under /src/test/resources?

Comment: Yes that's it. if you want, write this suggestion as an answer, and i'll mark it as a problem solver.